# Title of modal dialog in promoted links list

Tags: provider-hosted-app, promoted-links, dialog

I have a provider-hosted SharePoint app that I point to via a link in a promoted links list. Launch Behavior is set to "Dialog" and my app opens fine in the dialog window. My problem is that the title of the dialog is "Dialog". HTML generated: `<h1 title="Dialog" class="ms-dlgTitleText ms-accentText ms-dlg-heading" id="dialogTitleSpan" style="width: 718px;">Dialog</h1>`

When writing custom code and opening pages with showModalDialog there is an option to set title, but in a standard promoted links list, I can't find any option to set the title of the dialog window(I supposed that it uses the showModalDialog somehow in the background)?

[image: Dialog title]

I can probably fix this with code, but I'm curious to know if this can be achieved through configuration in the promoted links list.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog title is set by default to the Page Title.

So in case the page has no title, by default it will display "Dialog"

Comment: Already tested that. I have a title like this:
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>My custom title</title>`

A funny thing is that it sometimes the title says "working on it" instead of  "Dialog".

Comment: When you open that page directly is the title set properly?

Comment: Yes it does. If I open link in a new browser tab I get: ´<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>
 My custom title
</title>´
But I have some logic in code-behind Page_PreInit (CheckRedirectionStatus stuff that most SP apps use). Maybe that causes something to be executed in the wrong order...